# Can't detect item click in a listview from dialog in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

I'm trying to detect click on a ListView item which is inside a Dialog, which takes elements from an array. The array works fine, it displays correctly my results, however, when I try to click on an item, I don't receive any feedback.

Java code:

```
 public void createConstDialog(String[] textstring){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_editconstantformula, null);
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        builder.setTitle("Edit Values");
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_view_calculator_formula, R.id.constid, textstring);
        lv = (ListView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.list_view1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long viewId) {
                Log.d("touched", "true");

                mConstid = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.constid);
                mConstid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Log.d("touched", "true");
                    }
                });
                mConstvalue = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.constvaluez);


                mConstvalue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Log.d("touched", "true");
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


        builder.show();
    }
```

XML File R.layout.dialog_editconstantformula

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:padding="10dp" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

R.layout.activity_view_calculator_formula

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/constid"
        android:textColorHint="#afafaf"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="Variable"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/constvaluez"
        android:textColorHint="#afafaf"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="Value"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: May be due to some focus issue. Try setting the `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` to `false` for EditText inside your listview.

Comment: You're right! However, there's still no way retrieving a value from my EditText, if I try to click on the "ok" button, I get nullpointer exception

Comment: Try `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` and add it to top most of the XML where you have provided the elements for the listview (i.e. the root layout of list element). And remove `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode`. See if it helps...

Comment: Glad to be able to help out. :]

Comment: @ZhiKai Please post as answer below